# How can I combine .Select from two LINQ expressions into one?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code snippets.

```
protected IEnumerable<string> GetErrorsFromModelState()
{
    var errors =  ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors
            .Select(error => error.ErrorMessage));
    return errors;
}

protected IEnumerable<string> GetErrorsFromModelState()
{
    var exceptions = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors
            .Select(error => error.Exception));
    return exceptions;
}
```

Is there a way that I could combine these two so that GetErrorsFromModelState will return all the ErrorMessage and Exception values?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? You want an enumeration with all error messages first, followed by all exceptions? Or an enumeration of objects with properties `Error` and `Exception`? Or an enumeration of strings where each string is a concatenation of error message and exception message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - use the [Enumerable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993.aspx) extension method

```
protected IEnumerable<string> GetErrorsAndExceptionsFromModelState()
{
    var errors = ModelState
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage)
                    .Union(x.Value.Errors.Select(error => error.Exception.Message)));
    return errors;
}
```

Comment: `Join` may perform better than `Union` if you have no reason to actually do the union operation.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `Union`

```
protected IEnumerable<string> GetErrorsFromModelState()
{
    var exceptions = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors
        .Select(error => error.Exception));

    var errors =  ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors
        .Select(error => error.ErrorMessage));

    return exceptions.Union(errors);
}
```

or you could select them into a single collection

```
protected IEnumerable<string> GetErrorsFromModelState()
{
    var items = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors
        .SelectMany(error => 
                          {
                              var e = new List<string>();
                              e.Add(error.Exception);
                              e.Add(error.ErrorString);
                              return e;
                          }));

    return items;
}
```

Comment: You can use an array in your second example `.SelectMany(error => new [] { error.Exception, error.ErrorString }`

Comment: @Kirk - I tried the Union method but it gives me two errors: Error 4 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Exception>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' and  'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Exception>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Angela - note that in your OP `error.Exception` is an exception. To convert to a string you would either call `.ToString()` with stack trace, or `.Message` (just the message).

Comment: @nonnb - Thanks. Sorry I think it was my fault as my question didn't mention it was an exception and not a string.

Comment: @Angela I assumed it was a string because it's a string in your question.